# How do I insert a lot of rows into a temporary table in a stored procedure called from my C# code?

Tags: azure-sql-database

A little background first. I need to write a stored procedure that will grab everything in a table where the id is NOT in a list of other ids. Reading the Azure SQL docs it indicated that if you're going to have a large list of items in an IN or NOT IN clause then you should consider storing those items in a temporary table. So I figured I'd do that as I don't know how many potential items may be in this list. In my Azure Functions (C# code) I will have this list of IDs that I want to be placed into that temporary table. I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

I could not use a stored procedure and write the query in my Azure Functions and use a transaction and a for loop to insert each item into that temporary table (I think at least, I'm not very well-versed in this topic). I read that when inserting a lot of items it's best to batch it by putting it in one transaction.

If I do use a stored procedure, how do I do this? I have the list of IDs in my C# code but I don't know how I'd pass that in to the stored procedure (just one giant array?) or if there's any limits on how many items I could even pass in. And then in the stored procedure, how would it go about inserting this list of IDs that was passed in? Is there some sort of for loop syntax?

Hopefully there's a way to do this that is somewhat efficient.

Comment: How many ids are you talking about here?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. Each user will be different. I would like to say a few hundred max, and more realistically under a hundred, but I suppose there's the odd user who could just have a ton.

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be better to slightly alter my approach. Instead of creating a temp table, perhaps create a permanent table specific to each user's app install where I just stash each ID to be excluded in as the user gets them. Which would happen at a very low limit. So do it incrementally rather than try and fill up a temp table with all ids that they currently have.

Comment: If that works with your design, it sounds like a better way to go.